# I can not use single quotation problem in mpdf if DB row value contain any single quotation ' then it does not work

Tags: php, mysql, mpdf

I'm exporting php mysql to pdf by using mPDF. It is working very nicely. But I'm facing a problem if contain any **'** (single quotation) in the content. Please see below code. For example, if I write Name then I have no problem but if I write Name's then the code does not work. Even more, if $a1 value is David's then it does not work. So could anyone help me about it?

```
$html = '
    <html>
    <head>
    <table>
';

include("database.php");
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM test");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $html .='
        <tr>
          <td>Name: ' . $row['a1'] . '</td>
          <td colspan="3">Designation:' . $row['a2'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Contact phone number:' . $row['a3'] . '</td>
          <td colspan="3">E-mail:' . $row['a4'] . '</td>
        </tr>     
    ';
}

$html .= '
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
';

$path = (getenv('MPDF_ROOT')) ? getenv('MPDF_ROOT') : __DIR__;
require_once $path . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'margin_left' => 5,
    'margin_right' => 5,
    'margin_top' => 31,
    'margin_bottom' => 20,
    'margin_header' => 4,
    'format' => 'A4',
    'orientation' => 'P',
    'margin_footer' => 10
]);

$mpdf->SetHeader('Test');
$mpdf->setHTMLHeader('<img src="logo.jpg"/>');
$mpdf->setHTMLFooter('<img src="logo.jpg"/>');
$mpdf->SetTitle("Test");
$mpdf->SetAuthor("ohidul islam");
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in = 'iso-8859-4';
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$fname=Testform.".pdf";
$mpdf->Output($fname, 'I');
```

Comment: Have you tried [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)?  `htmlspecialchars($row['a1'])`

Comment: Okay let me try, but if it contain in body text not in db then ?

Comment: For the first case, when you want to write **Name's** in place of Name, you have to use the escape character "\", like this: `<td>Name\'s: ' . $row['a1'] . '</td>`. For the second case, you can give a try to method **json_encode()** too, example: `$mpdf->WriteHTML(json_encode($html));`.